# jQuery FadeTo() bg on rollover, IMG animate().width height

Tags: jquery

I have been reading StackOverflow for a while and now I have a question I cannot find an answer to.

i am trying to fade a background and increase on img size on rollover.

I have tried animate() and fadeTo(), however, the entire div fades. Do I need to absolute position my images over the div and not within it? img or img?

Is that the only way to get items within a div to not fade along with the background?

Thanks!
Jason

Comment: What I am trying to do is get all images, but the 1 I am hovering on to change opacity. How do I get the currently mouseover'd item? I am looking for something like :selected right? However that only works for form stuff it seems like. 

This is sort of what I want to do... 
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.ipost a').mouseover(function() {
  $('a').fadeTo('fast',.25);
  $('#tposts').animate({
   opacity: 0.25
     }, 200, function() {
  });
  $(this).fadeTo('fast',1.0);
 });
  });
</script>

any better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use absolute positioning, if you fade the div that is wrapping the image then everything in the div will fade.